# Android Kotlin: Exception running python script with Chaquopy

Tags: python, android, kotlin, chaquopy

As I haven't found an Android library to compare two .wav audio files (only found [musicg](https://github.com/loisaidasam/musicg) which is not working for me) I decided to try one of the many I've found for Python, in concrete, [AudioCompare](https://github.com/charlesconnell/AudioCompare).

For that I've followed the [chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/) page instructions and I was able to install v14 with no problems, and now I am able to run Python scripts from my Android app, the problem is the audio compare library I'm trying to run is throwing an exception, that is:

```
com.chaquo.python.PyException: OSError: This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives needed will not function, see issue 3770.
```

I don't know about Python, but I'm quite sure the exception is launched in Matcher.py module (don't know hot to check the line number as the exception is not giving me this information), but anyway I'll paste all files just in case:

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from error import *
from Matcher import Matcher
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def audio_matcher():
    """Our main control flow."""

    parser = ArgumentParser(
        description="Compare two audio files to determine if one "
                    "was derived from the other. Supports WAVE and MP3.",
        prog="audiomatch")
    parser.add_argument("-f", action="append",
                        required=False, dest="files",
                        default=list(),
                        help="A file to examine.")
    parser.add_argument("-d", action="append",
                        required=False, dest="dirs",
                        default=list(),
                        help="A directory of files to examine. "
                             "Directory must contain only audio files.")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    from os.path import dirname, join
    filename1 = join(dirname(__file__), "file1.wav")
    filename2 = join(dirname(__file__), "file2.wav")

    search_paths = [filename1, filename2]
    #search_paths = args.dirs + args.files

    if len(search_paths) != 2:
        die("Must provide exactly two input files or directories.")

    code = 0
    # Use our matching system
    matcher = Matcher(search_paths[0], search_paths[1])
    results = matcher.match()

    for match in results:
        if not match.success:
            code = 1
            warn(match.message)
        else:
            print(match)

    return code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exit(audio_matcher())
```

Matcher.py (from https://github.com/charlesconnell/AudioCompare):

```
import math
import itertools
from FFT import FFT
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from InputFile import InputFile
import multiprocessing
#from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import os
import stat
from error import *
from common import *


BUCKET_SIZE = 20
BUCKETS = 4
BITS_PER_NUMBER = int(math.ceil(math.log(BUCKET_SIZE, 2)))
assert((BITS_PER_NUMBER * BUCKETS) <= 32)

NORMAL_CHUNK_SIZE = 1024
NORMAL_SAMPLE_RATE = 44100.0

SCORE_THRESHOLD = 5


class FileResult(BaseResult):
    """The result of fingerprinting
    an entire audio file."""
    def __init__(self, fingerprints, file_len, filename):
        super(FileResult, self).__init__(True, "")
        self.fingerprints = fingerprints
        self.file_len = file_len
        self.filename = filename

    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename


class ChunkInfo(object):
    """These objects will be the values in
    our master hashes that map fingerprints
    to instances of this class."""
    def __init__(self, chunk_index, filename):
        self.chunk_index = chunk_index
        self.filename = filename

    def __str__(self):
        return "Chunk: {c}, File: {f}".format(c=self.chunk_index, f=self.filename)


class MatchResult(BaseResult):
    """The result of comparing two files."""
    def __init__(self, file1, file2, file1_len, file2_len, score):
        super(MatchResult, self).__init__(True, "")
        self.file1 = file1
        self.file2 = file2
        self.file1_len = file1_len
        self.file2_len = file2_len
        self.score = score

    def __str__(self):
        short_file1 = os.path.basename(self.file1)
        short_file2 = os.path.basename(self.file2)
        if self.score > SCORE_THRESHOLD:
            if self.file1_len < self.file2_len:
                return "MATCH {f1} {f2} ({s})".format(f1=short_file1, f2=short_file2, s=self.score)
            else:
                return "MATCH {f2} {f1} ({s})".format(f1=short_file1, f2=short_file2, s=self.score)
        else:
            return "NO MATCH"


def _to_fingerprints(freq_chunks):
    """Examine the results of running chunks of audio
    samples through FFT. For each chunk, look at the frequencies
    that are loudest in each "bucket." A bucket is a series of
    frequencies. Return the indices of the loudest frequency in each
    bucket in each chunk. These indices will be encoded into
    a single number per chunk."""
    chunks = len(freq_chunks)
    fingerprints = np.zeros(chunks, dtype=np.uint32)
    # Examine each chunk independently
    for chunk in range(chunks):
        fingerprint = 0
        for bucket in range(BUCKETS):
            start_index = bucket * BUCKET_SIZE
            end_index = (bucket + 1) * BUCKET_SIZE
            bucket_vals = freq_chunks[chunk][start_index:end_index]
            max_index = bucket_vals.argmax()
            fingerprint += (max_index << (bucket * BITS_PER_NUMBER))
        fingerprints[chunk] = fingerprint

    # return the indexes of the loudest frequencies
    return fingerprints


def _file_fingerprint(filename):
    """Read the samples from the files, run them through FFT,
    find the loudest frequencies to use as fingerprints,
    turn those into a hash table.
    Returns a 2-tuple containing the length
    of the file in seconds, and the hash table."""

    # Open the file
    try:
        file = InputFile(filename)

        # Read samples from the input files, divide them
        # into chunks by time, and convert the samples in each
        # chunk into the frequency domain.
        # The chunk size is dependent on the sample rate of the
        # file. It is important that each chunk represent the
        # same amount of time, regardless of the sample
        # rate of the file.
        chunk_size_adjust_factor = (NORMAL_SAMPLE_RATE / file.get_sample_rate())
        fft = FFT(file, int(NORMAL_CHUNK_SIZE / chunk_size_adjust_factor))
        series = fft.series()

        file_len = file.get_total_samples() / file.get_sample_rate()

        file.close()

        # Find the indices of the loudest frequencies
        # in each "bucket" of frequencies (for every chunk).
        # These loud frequencies will become the
        # fingerprints that we'll use for matching.
        # Each chunk will be reduced to a tuple of
        # 4 numbers which are 4 of the loudest frequencies
        # in that chunk.
        # Convert each tuple in winners to a single
        # number. This number is unique for each possible
        # tuple. This hopefully makes things more
        # efficient.
        fingerprints = _to_fingerprints(series)

    except Exception as e:
        return FileErrorResult(str(e))

    return FileResult(fingerprints, file_len, filename)


class Matcher(object):
    """Create an instance of this class to use our matching system."""

    def __init__(self, dir1, dir2):
        """The two arguments should be strings that are
        file or directory paths. For files, we will simply
        examine these files. For directories, we will scan
        them for files."""
        self.dir1 = dir1
        self.dir2 = dir2

    @staticmethod
    def __search_dir(dir):
        """Returns the regular files residing
        in the given directory, OR if the input
        is a regular file, return a 1-element
        list containing this file. All paths
        returned will be absolute paths."""

        results = []
        # Get the absolute path of our search dir
        abs_dir = os.path.abspath(dir)
        # Get info about the directory provide
        dir_stat = os.stat(abs_dir)

        # If it's really a file, just
        # return the name of it
        if stat.S_ISREG(dir_stat.st_mode):
            results.append(abs_dir)
            return results

        # If it's neither a file nor directory,
        # bail out
        if not stat.S_ISDIR(dir_stat.st_mode):
            die("{d} is not a directory or a regular file.".format(d=abs_dir))

        # Scan through the contents of the
        # directory (non-recursively).
        contents = os.listdir(abs_dir)
        for node in contents:
            abs_node = abs_dir + os.sep + node
            node_stat = os.stat(abs_node)
            # If we find a regular file, add
            # that to our results list, otherwise
            # warn the user.
            if stat.S_ISREG(node_stat.st_mode):
                results.append(abs_node)
            else:
                warn("An inode that is not a regular file was found at {f}".format(abs_node))

        return results

    @staticmethod
    def __combine_hashes(files):
        """Take a list of FileResult objects and
        create a hash that maps all of their fingerprints
        to ChunkInfo objects."""
        master = defaultdict(list)
        for f in files:
            for chunk in range(len(f.fingerprints)):
                hash = f.fingerprints[chunk]
                master[hash].append(ChunkInfo(chunk, f.filename))

        return master

    @staticmethod
    def __file_lengths(files):
        """Take a list of FileResult objects and
        create a hash that maps their filenames
        to the length of each file, in seconds."""
        results = {}
        for f in files:
            results[f.filename] = f.file_len

        return results

    @staticmethod
    def __report_file_matches(file, master_hash, file_lengths):
        """Find files from the master hash that match
        the given file.
        @param file A FileResult object that is our query
        @param master_hash The data to search through
        @param file_lengths A hash mapping filenames to file lengths
        @return A list of MatchResult objects, one for every file
        that was represented in master_hash"""

        results = []

        # A hash that maps filenames to "offset" hashes. Then,
        # an offset hash maps the difference in chunk numbers of
        # the matches we will find.
        # We'll map those differences to the number of matches
        # found with that difference.
        # This allows us to see if many fingerprints
        # from different files occurred at the same
        # time offsets relative to each other.
        file_match_offsets = {}
        for f in file_lengths:
            file_match_offsets[f] = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

        # For each chunk in the query file
        for query_chunk_index in range(len(file.fingerprints)):
            # See if that chunk's fingerprint is in our master hash
            chunk_fingerprint = file.fingerprints[query_chunk_index]
            if chunk_fingerprint in master_hash:
                # If it is, record the offset between our query chunk
                # and the found chunk
                for matching_chunk in master_hash[chunk_fingerprint]:
                    offset = matching_chunk.chunk_index - query_chunk_index
                    file_match_offsets[matching_chunk.filename][offset] += 1

        # For each file that was in master_hash,
        # we examine the offsets of the matching fingerprints we found
        for f in file_match_offsets:
            offsets = file_match_offsets[f]

            # The length of the shorter file is important
            # to deciding whether two audio files match.
            min_len = min(file_lengths[f], file.file_len)

            # max_offset is the highest number of times that two matching
            # hash keys were found with the same time difference
            # relative to each other.
            if len(offsets) != 0:
                max_offset = max(offsets.values())
            else:
                max_offset = 0

            # The score is the ratio of max_offset (as explained above)
            # to the length of the shorter file. A short file that should
            # match another file will result in less matching fingerprints
            # than a long file would, so we take this into account. At the
            # same time, a long file that should *not* match another file
            # will generate a decent number of matching fingerprints by
            # pure chance, so this corrects for that as well.
            if min_len > 0:
                score = max_offset / min_len
            else:
                score = 0

            results.append(MatchResult(file.filename, f, file.file_len, file_lengths[f], score))

        return results

    def match(self):
        """Takes two AbstractInputFiles as input,
        and returns a boolean as output, indicating
        if the two files match."""

        dir1_files = Matcher.__search_dir(self.dir1)
        dir2_files = Matcher.__search_dir(self.dir2)

        # Try to determine how many
        # processors are in the computer
        # we're running on, to determine
        # the appropriate amount of parallelism
        # to use
        try:
            cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        except NotImplementedError:
            cpus = 1

        # Construct a process pool to give the task of
        # fingerprinting audio files
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cpus)
        try:
            # Get the fingerprints from each input file.
            # Do this using a pool of processes in order
            # to parallelize the work neatly.
            map1_result = pool.map_async(_file_fingerprint, dir1_files)
            map2_result = pool.map_async(_file_fingerprint, dir2_files)

            # Wait for pool to finish processing
            pool.close()
            pool.join()

            # Get results from process pool
            dir1_results = map1_result.get()
            dir2_results = map2_result.get()

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pool.terminate()
            raise

        results = []

        # If there was an error in fingerprinting a file,
        # add a special ErrorResult to our results list
        results.extend([x for x in dir1_results if not x.success])
        results.extend([x for x in dir2_results if not x.success])

        # Proceed only with fingerprints that were computed
        # successfully
        dir1_successes = [x for x in dir1_results if x.success and x.file_len > 0]
        dir2_successes = [x for x in dir2_results if x.success and x.file_len > 0]

        # Empty files should match other empty files
        # Our matching algorithm will not report these as a match,
        # so we have to make a special case for it.
        dir1_empty_files = [x for x in dir1_results if x.success and x.file_len == 0]
        dir2_empty_files = [x for x in dir2_results if x.success and x.file_len == 0]

        # Every empty file should match every other empty file
        for empty_file1, empty_file2 in itertools.product(dir1_empty_files, dir2_empty_files):
            results.append(MatchResult(empty_file1.filename, empty_file2.filename, empty_file1.file_len, empty_file2.file_len, SCORE_THRESHOLD + 1))

        # This maps filenames to the lengths of the files
        dir1_file_lengths = Matcher.__file_lengths(dir1_successes)
        dir2_file_lengths = Matcher.__file_lengths(dir2_successes)

        # Get the combined sizes of the files in our two search
        # paths
        dir1_size = sum(dir1_file_lengths.values())
        dir2_size = sum(dir2_file_lengths.values())

        # Whichever search path has more data in it is the
        # one we want to put in the master hash, and then query
        # via the other one
        if dir1_size < dir2_size:
            dir_successes = dir1_successes
            master_hash = Matcher.__combine_hashes(dir2_successes)
            file_lengths = dir2_file_lengths
        else:
            dir_successes = dir2_successes
            master_hash = Matcher.__combine_hashes(dir1_successes)
            file_lengths = dir1_file_lengths

        # Loop through each file in the first search path our
        # program was given.
        for file in dir_successes:
            # For each file, check its fingerprints against those in the
            # second search path. For matching
            # fingerprints, look up the the times (chunk number)
            # that the fingerprint occurred
            # in each file. Store the time differences in
            # offsets. The point of this is to see if there
            # are many matching fingerprints at the
            # same time difference relative to each
            # other. This indicates that the two files
            # contain similar audio.
            file_matches = Matcher.__report_file_matches(file, master_hash, file_lengths)
            results.extend(file_matches)

        return results
```

May be after all the effort it won't work, but at least I'd like to give it a try.

Many help in order to be able to run this matcher script will be much appreciated.

Full exception:

```
0 = {StackTraceElement@19282} "<python>.java.android.__init__(__init__.py:140)"
1 = {StackTraceElement@19283} "<python>.multiprocessing.synchronize.__init__(synchronize.py:57)"
2 = {StackTraceElement@19284} "<python>.multiprocessing.synchronize.__init__(synchronize.py:162)"
3 = {StackTraceElement@19285} "<python>.multiprocessing.context.Lock(context.py:68)"
4 = {StackTraceElement@19286} "<python>.multiprocessing.queues.__init__(queues.py:336)"
5 = {StackTraceElement@19287} "<python>.multiprocessing.context.SimpleQueue(context.py:113)"
6 = {StackTraceElement@19288} "<python>.multiprocessing.pool._setup_queues(pool.py:343)"
7 = {StackTraceElement@19289} "<python>.multiprocessing.pool.__init__(pool.py:191)"
8 = {StackTraceElement@19290} "<python>.multiprocessing.context.Pool(context.py:119)"
9 = {StackTraceElement@19291} "<python>.Matcher.match(Matcher.py:306)"
10 = {StackTraceElement@19292} "<python>.main.audio_matcher(main.py:38)"
11 = {StackTraceElement@19293} "<python>.chaquopy_java.call(chaquopy_java.pyx:354)"
12 = {StackTraceElement@19294} "<python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_PyObject_callAttrThrowsNative(chaquopy_java.pyx:326)"
13 = {StackTraceElement@19295} "com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrowsNative(Native Method)"
14 = {StackTraceElement@19296} "com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrows(PyObject.java:232)"
15 = {StackTraceElement@19297} "com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttr(PyObject.java:221)"
16 = {StackTraceElement@19298} "com.testmepracticetool.toeflsatactexamprep.ui.activities.main.MainActivity.startActivity(MainActivity.kt:104)"
17 = {StackTraceElement@19299} "com.testmepracticetool.toeflsatactexamprep.ui.activities.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:80)"
18 = {StackTraceElement@19300} "android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)"
19 = {StackTraceElement@19301} "android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)"
20 = {StackTraceElement@19302} "android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)"
21 = {StackTraceElement@19303} "android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)"
22 = {StackTraceElement@19304} "android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)"
23 = {StackTraceElement@19305} "android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)"
24 = {StackTraceElement@19306} "android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)"
25 = {StackTraceElement@19307} "android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)"
26 = {StackTraceElement@19308} "android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)"
27 = {StackTraceElement@19309} "android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)"
28 = {StackTraceElement@19310} "android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)"
29 = {StackTraceElement@19311} "android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)"
30 = {StackTraceElement@19312} "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)"
31 = {StackTraceElement@19313} "com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)"
32 = {StackTraceElement@19314} "com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)"
```

---

Edit 1: New exception after @mhsmith great help:

After replacing the import multithreading now I get the following exception:

```
com.chaquo.python.PyException: AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing.dummy' has no attribute 'cpu_count'

0 = {StackTraceElement@19430} "<python>.Matcher.match(Matcher.py:300)"
1 = {StackTraceElement@19431} "<python>.main.audio_matcher(main.py:38)"
2 = {StackTraceElement@19432} "<python>.chaquopy_java.call(chaquopy_java.pyx:354)"
3 = {StackTraceElement@19433} "<python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_PyObject_callAttrThrowsNative(chaquopy_java.pyx:326)"
4 = {StackTraceElement@19434} "com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrowsNative(Native Method)"
5 = {StackTraceElement@19435} "com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrows(PyObject.java:232)"
6 = {StackTraceElement@19436} "com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttr(PyObject.java:221)"
7 = {StackTraceElement@19437} "com.testmepracticetool.toeflsatactexamprep.ui.activities.main.MainActivity.startActivity(MainActivity.kt:104)"
8 = {StackTraceElement@19438} "com.testmepracticetool.toeflsatactexamprep.ui.activities.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:80)"
9 = {StackTraceElement@19439} "android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)"
10 = {StackTraceElement@19440} "android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)"
11 = {StackTraceElement@19441} "android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)"
12 = {StackTraceElement@19442} "android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)"
13 = {StackTraceElement@19443} "android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)"
14 = {StackTraceElement@19444} "android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)"
15 = {StackTraceElement@19445} "android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)"
16 = {StackTraceElement@19446} "android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)"
17 = {StackTraceElement@19447} "android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)"
18 = {StackTraceElement@19448} "android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)"
19 = {StackTraceElement@19449} "android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)"
20 = {StackTraceElement@19450} "android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)"
21 = {StackTraceElement@19451} "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)"
22 = {StackTraceElement@19452} "com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)"
23 = {StackTraceElement@19453} "com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)"
```

Comment: The exception should contain a full stack trace. Please find it in the [Logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174), and edit your question to include it.

Comment: Thenks for replying @mhsmith. I've added full exception. Let's see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the [Chaquopy documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#multiprocessing):

> Because Android doesn’t support POSIX semaphores, most of the `multiprocessing` APIs will fail with the error “This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation”. The simplest solution is to use `multiprocessing.dummy` instead.

I see you've already attempted to do this, but the correct way is to replace
`import multiprocessing` with `import multiprocessing.dummy as multiprocessing`.

---

Edit: for the second exception, the simplest solution is to rewrite the import statements as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

And then remove the `multiprocessing.` prefix from the places where those names are used in the rest of the file.

Comment: Thank you very much again @mhsmith for you great help. Your solution worked, but now I get a different exception (see my edit). I hope you are able to help me with this, as it were you the only person who replied.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer, and I've also edited your question to restore the original stack trace so my original answer still makes sense.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't designed for extended conversations, so if you have any more problems in this area, please create an issue on our [GitHub page](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues).